# How to see previous version of a Docker image?

Tags: docker, dotnet

I am looking for a netframework Docker image with .net 4.7.2 and netcoreapp2.2. I searched on the main docker website: [DockerHub, .NET Framework
By Microsoft](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework) without success. I also check the [Microsoft website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/) just in case.

Is there a way to see previous version of a Docker image? (Especially for the .NET Framework)

Something to allow me to fill this kind of table:

```
| docker image                         | framework | core  | aspcore |
|--------------------------------------|-----------|-------|---------|
| microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.8-sdk   | 4.8       | 3.0   | ?       |
| microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk | 4.7.2     |  2.1? | ?       |
|                                      | 4.7.1     | ?     | ?       |
|                                      | 4.7       | ?     | ?       |
|                                      | 4.6.2     | ?     | ?       |
|                                      | 4.6.1     | ?     | ?       |
|                                      | 4.6       | ?     | ?       |
|                                      | 4.5.2     | ?     | ?       |
|                                      | 4.5.1     | ?     | ?       |
|                                      | 4.5.0     | ?     | ?       |
```

Comment: Yes....check images and timestamp before doing the same in online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker image inspect` - will show available information on the container ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_inspect/))

`docker image history [your OPTIONS] imagename` - Shows history of the container ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_history/))